# Testcafe Browserstack IE11- Clicking on button doesn't work

Tags: testing, internet-explorer, automated-tests, testcafe, browserstack

Error: Button click doesn't perform action as expected, page is being Idle

Current behavior: It's clicking on a button but it's not performing any action

Expected behavior: Manually it works! expected the button click should move to the next page

Tried using Press key, hover, Client function for Selector

Unfortunately I couldn't provide more details of the application but I will appreciate providing workarounds

Comment: Are you using the latest TestCafe version (v1.9.1)? Can you reproduce this behavior with a local browser? If you cannot provide access to your app, could you please create a separate sample page that can be used to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I was using 1.8.8 I will try with the new version.

Comment: @AndreyBelym thank you it works good on new version!

Comment: Thank you for confirming that the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it was fixed in TestCafe v1.9.1.